# With XCode 8 How Do I Target My App To Run on macOS also (it already runs on iPhone / iPad)?

Tags: xcode, app-store, macos-sierra

Can someone show me what I change in my project in XCode so that my app will also deploy to a Mac?

For example, I'm running a Mac Mini but I cannot seem to run my app on the actual Mac, even though it is a Universal app and runs on both iPhone and iPad platforms.  My app is already deployed to the app store ( https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cyapass/id1183137527?mt=8 ) and I've tried to install it to the Mac that way, but that doesn't work either.

Is this possible through a simple change in the XCode project?
Or, do I have to create a new project that targets the Mac specifically?

If you have screenshots from XCode those would be greatly appreciated if the change is made in the XCode project.

Comment: Which frameworks does it rely on? E.g. UIKit — UIViewController, UIView, UIColor, everything UI* — is for iOS only. So you can't just deploy it to a Mac.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that & that could be a valid answer, such as "it is not possible, you must create a new XCode project".  It is dependent upon all of those libraries you mention I believe. I thought (hoped) that there were some common APIs beneath everything which would allow me to target all Apple OSes but I should've known better. Just thought apple was ahead in that area.  Plus, the word Universal...Microsoft uses it the same way...it means "lots of places, but not _everywhere_".  Universal in the common vernacular means _everywhere_.  Oh well.

Comment: There are lots of common APIs — e.g. anything NS*, CG*, CA* — but Apple has made a policy decision that touch interfaces and traditional interfaces are different and should be written separately. So the intention is that your model and even any custom drawing stuff transfers, but your interface controls are distinct. 'Universal' is unfortunate nomenclature, meaning merely "pad and phone". Is it the sort of application where a fresh interface for an existing model layer is a meaningful way to port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are some frameworks which are not applicable for OS X that iOS development depend on, such as the `UIKit`. You can see the full list [here](https://apple-frameworks-checker.herokuapp.com/).

[Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/), once done, can hopefully make the transition from iOS to OS X easier.

Although, you won't necessarily need to create a new XCode Project, as you can share the common frameworks and logic in-between the two platforms.

You could essentially structure your code like so ([inspired by another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953155/how-do-i-have-an-ios-app-and-os-x-app-in-the-same-project/33953496#33953496))

```
- Workspace
    - Shared Code
        - File1.m       Target: iOS and OSX
    - iOS
        - File2.m       Target: iOS
    - OSX
        - File3.m       Target: OSX
```

It is although important when doing so to set the appropriate targets of each individual file.

Last but not least, Apple has previously, during WWDC13, given a talk about [how to bring iOS Apps to OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/216/). Note that the talk can only be seen using either the WWDC App or Safari. I have previously found this talk helpful myself once I needed to implement an OS X version of an existing iOS app.

Comment: great solid answer with numerous references and a lot of great information that helps me get closer to the answer I'm looking for.  Awarding bounty.  Thanks for writing this up.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible through a simple change in the XCode project?

No, it isn't. AppKit and UIKit are utterly different from one another. Even common frameworks such as Core Graphics have different APIs. Basically, you just have to rewrite the app. Your core logic (the model) can be in common, but the workings of the iOS app and the macOS app will be completely separate codebases.